# Customize Shopify sections in Dawn theme

Tags: html, css, shopify, liquid, figma

Is there a place for people like me with very, very, little experience in what I call “true development” to get help. Specifically help with coding a couple shopify sections. I hired a “developer” that did limited design work, I gave basic specs for my shopify homepage based on basic shopify functionality…So far so good, time to develop, there would need to be 2 custom coded sections since no premium theme offered both sections together, separately yes.  Nonetheless the “Developer” told me the only way to get what I wanted was developing a pagefly homepage, or full custom theme, but he didn’t have time to do (couldn’t do it). I added all the sections and converted the figma file to css/HTML so I could follow the padding and image sizes to ensure mobile was correct. But now.

I need help with writting code for two sections so that I can wrap this up. I was able to create an option for both section in my theme, but adding the code is best left for experts and the OG type developers.  Not the drag and droppers. (Nothing wrong with those peeps), just I need something a little more advanced.  Any help, guidance, anything would be greatly appreciated. I was super excited I figured out how to center the menu in Dawn theme with the logo left. If that explains my skillset.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.